# Добавление текста из JSON обработчиком клика в jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Имеется html файл с несколькими формами ввода, текст из которых нужно вставить в плейсхолдеры текста (обозначены фигурными скобками), получаемого из [JSON](https://api.myjson.com/bins/jcmhn).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge"/>
    <title>Ryaba Chicka</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Курочка Ряба</h1>
        <form>
            <input id="1st" type="text" placeholder="var1"/>
            <input id="2nd" type="text" placeholder="var2"/>
            <input id="3rd" type="text" placeholder="var3"/>
            <input id="4th" type="text" placeholder="var4"/>
            <input id="5th" type="text" placeholder="var5"/>
            <input id="6th" type="text" placeholder="var6"/>
            <input id="7th" type="text" placeholder="speach"/>
            <button type="button" class="btn">Создать</button>
        </form>
        <div class="result"></div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

Пробую постепенно модифицировать скрипт от простого к сложному, удалось вывести текст, но надо заменить его в фигурных скобках на соответствующий input. Как это сделать? js-скрипт:

```
//обработчик клика
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.btn').click(function(){
        $.getJSON('https://api.myjson.com/bins/jcmhn',
                   function(data){
                        $(".result").html(data.text);

          }
          );
    }
    );
 }
);
```

Попытка применить ответ, не дала работу кода. HTML  выводит мертвый.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge"/>
    <title>Ryaba Chicka</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <h1>Курочка Ряба</h1>
    <form>
        <input id="1st" type="text" placeholder="var1"/>
        <input id="2nd" type="text" placeholder="var2"/>
        <input id="3rd" type="text" placeholder="var3"/>
        <input id="4th" type="text" placeholder="var4"/>
        <input id="5th" type="text" placeholder="var5"/>
        <input id="6th" type="text" placeholder="var6"/>
        <input id="7th" type="text" placeholder="speach"/>
        <button type="button" class="btn">Создать</button>
    </form>
    <div class="result"></div>
</div>


    <script src="script.js"></script>


</body>
</html>

$(document).ready(function(){
            $('.btn').click(function(){
                    $.getJSON('https://api.myjson.com/bins/jcmhn',
                        function(data){
                            zzz = data.text;
                            $.each($('input'), function (key1, value1) {
                                varr = $(value1).attr('placeholder');
                                varr1 = '{' + varr + "}";
                                text = value1.value; // Значение поля ввода
                                $.each(zzz, function (key2,value2) {
                                    zzz[key2] = value2.replace(varr1, text);
                                });
                            });

                            $(".result").html(zzz);

                        }
                    );
                }
            );
        }
);
```

Comment: $(".result").html(data.text[0]);

Comment: у вас `data.text` это массив

Comment: Отлично, а как теперь в каждый плейсхолдер {var*} добавить соответствующие значения форм input?

Comment: @StepanSokol ну вы js-то указывайте в тегах <script>тут js</script>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно так:

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.btn').click(function(){
                    $.getJSON('https://api.myjson.com/bins/jcmhn',
                        function(data){
                            zzz = data.text;
                            $.each($('input'), function (key1, value1) {
                                varr = $(value1).attr('placeholder');
                                varr1 = '{' + varr + "}";
                                text = value1.value; // Значение поля ввода
                                $.each(zzz, function (key2,value2) {
                                    zzz[key2] = value2.replace(varr1, text);
                                });
                            });

                            $(".result").html(zzz);

                        }
                    );
                }
            );
        }
    );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge"/>
    <title>Ryaba Chicka</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <h1>Курочка Ряба</h1>
    <form>
        <input id="1st" type="text" placeholder="var1"/>
        <input id="2nd" type="text" placeholder="var2"/>
        <input id="3rd" type="text" placeholder="var3"/>
        <input id="4th" type="text" placeholder="var4"/>
        <input id="5th" type="text" placeholder="var5"/>
        <input id="6th" type="text" placeholder="var6"/>
        <input id="7th" type="text" placeholder="speach"/>
        <button type="button" class="btn">Создать</button>
    </form>
    <div class="result"></div>
</div>
```

Пример отдельно для автора по оформлению кода.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge"/>
    <title>Ryaba Chicka</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <h1>Курочка Ряба</h1>
    <form>
        <input id="1st" type="text" placeholder="var1"/>
        <input id="2nd" type="text" placeholder="var2"/>
        <input id="3rd" type="text" placeholder="var3"/>
        <input id="4th" type="text" placeholder="var4"/>
        <input id="5th" type="text" placeholder="var5"/>
        <input id="6th" type="text" placeholder="var6"/>
        <input id="7th" type="text" placeholder="speach"/>
        <button type="button" class="btn">Создать</button>
    </form>
    <div class="result"></div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript">
    //обработчик клика
    $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.btn').click(function(){
                    $.getJSON('https://api.myjson.com/bins/jcmhn',
                        function(data){
                            $('input').length;
                            zzz = data.text;
                            $.each($('input'), function (key1, value1) {
                                varr = $(value1).attr('placeholder');
                                varr1 = '{' + varr + "}";
                                text = value1.value; // Значение поля ввода
                                $.each(zzz, function (key2,value2) {
                                    zzz[key2] = value2.replace(varr1, text);
                                });
                            });

                            $(".result").html(zzz);

                        }
                    );
                }
            );
        }
    );
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: А почему у меня этот код может не работать?

Comment: @StepanSokol Если у Вас всё в точности, как в примере, то должно работать. 1. Должна быть подключена библиотека jquery. 2. Placeholders должны называться так же. Выложите скрин полного кода, тогда можно будет точно сказать.

Comment: Получилось я Ваш код скопипастил. В общем, HTML как бы мертвый, кнопка не работает.

Comment: @StepanSokol, что значит мёртвый? https://codepen.io/den131313/pen/gObZNVw Вы jquery точно подключили ДО основного скрипта?

Comment: То есть формы есть, кнопка есть, но текст не подтягивается при ее нажатии

Comment: @StepanSokol посмотрите пример на codepen. Всё работает. Вы точно корректно всё скопировали?

Comment: @StepanSokol добавил в ответ снизу пример по оформлению кода.

Comment: Встроенный скрипт заработал! Спасибо! А есть идеи почему могло не работать?

Answer (score -2):

в HTML изменил ID инпутов на var1 и т.д.

```js
$('.btn').click(function () {
    $.getJSON('https://api.myjson.com/bins/jcmhn', (data) => {
        let modified = data.text.map((str) =>
             str.replace((/\{.{4,6}\}/g), (item) => 
                    $(`#${(/\{(.{4,6})\}/).exec(item)[1]}`).val()
             )
        )

        $('.result').text(modified.join(". "));
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <h1>Курочка Ряба</h1>
    <form>
        <input id="var1" type="text" placeholder="var1" />
        <input id="var2" type="text" placeholder="var2" />
        <input id="var3" type="text" placeholder="var3" />
        <input id="var4" type="text" placeholder="var4" />
        <input id="var5" type="text" placeholder="var5" />
        <input id="var6" type="text" placeholder="var6" />
        <input id="speach" type="text" placeholder="speach" />
        <button type="button" class="btn">Создать</button>
    </form>
    <div class="result"></div>
</div>
```

Если нужны именно ваши ID элементов, то можно таблицу соответствий (объект с ключами var1, var2 и т.д)
Например

```
let elemsMap = {
 var1: "#1st"
}
```

вызывая `elemMap[var1]`, будем получать ID нужного элемента.